# Excel grab address to start y values series

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have the string $F$50 created by the CONCATENATE function.
I also have a scatter plot where the selected data is like this: 
=SERIES(,data!$A$4:$A$404,data!$F$4:$F$404,1)

I want to replace $F$4 in the SERIES function with $F$50, so my plot's y-values start there. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Thanks for posting your question.  Can you clarify a bit about *how* you want to do the replace? I'm guessing you want to do it so that it automatically updates the chart when the result in `$F$50` changes?

Comment: Yup, if $F$50 changes to $F$44, I'd want the graph to pull y-values from $F$44 to $F$404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel chart series don't play nice when you try to lay spreadsheet functions into their definitions, as you've probably noticed.  One way to achieve what you're describing is through defining helper columns:

[image: Excel snip]

Here I've constructed a random parabola as example data and laid in one way of constructing the helper columns to allow tuning of the plotted data range. Changing the row specified in `E1` adjusts which portion of the data is replaced by `NA()`; Excel charts skip plotting of any points containing the `#N/A` error.

I know I've implemented this in a slightly different setup than you describe in your question, but it should be pretty easy to adapt either your worksheet or the formulas to make it work.

If you want to do this without adding helper columns, I believe VBA will be necessary.